# Customising Django Crispy forms for formatted user input (formatted by the user)

Tags: django, forms, formatting

In a Django project, I have used crispy forms to generate a form for a user to enter a title and a comment. For the comment section, I wish the user to be able to format their input (e.g add bold and italics tags, and also embed youtube videos, so use embed snippets). This is typical of a wordpress widget (admin) which allows text formatting for any text entry. Is it possible to do this with Django's Crispy forms, and if so, what is the best way forward? I am looking for suggestions for documentation, imports (any existing libraries compatible with Django?), as I as I couldn't find any, or an idea as to how to implement this manually. e.g. specifically, in which 'file' would it be implemented. 
View of the html page (current)
[View of the current form and text input on the comment area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtqpD.png)

I've looked at the other questions-answers, but none answers this specifically.

This is the sort of functioanlity I would like to add to the form text input (for the content/comment box only)

[Desired text input formatting options added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrqR9.png)

The current **post_form.html** code is below

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Post your message</legend>
            {{form|crispy}}
        </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{object.author.profile.image.url}}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"}}</small>
      {% if object.author == user %}
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}"> Update </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}"> Delete </a>
        </div>
      {% endif %}


        </div>
    <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py** (relevant to the form)

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone #don't forget to add this
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py** (again relating to the form)

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Post #import the Models Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)


from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.



class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post #what model to query in order to create the list
    template_name = 'socialmedia/home.html' 

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']#the minus sign before the -date_posted makes it newest first
    paginate_by = 10

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post #what model to query in order to create the list
    template_name = 'socialmedia/user_posts.html' 
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10    

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')



class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post 


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

    model = Post 
    fields=['title','content']


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user #set author to current loggged in user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
        model = Post 
        fields=['title','content']

        def form_valid(self,form):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user 
            return super().form_valid(form)
        #this only lets the user of the post update the post.....
        def test_func(self):
            post = self.get_object() #this gets the current post
            if self.request.user == post.author:
                return True
            return False

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post 
    success_url = '/'
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object() #this gets the current post
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: What all have you tried doing? Be sure to let us know about your attempts and we can try fixing them from there. And, as always, welcome to Stackoverflow! :)

Comment: In the first instance, before I looked into javascript manually being added to the html, I was hoping there were some crispy forms compatible suggestions...imports etc